# Why does this label go off screen when anchored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I want to anchor this label but for some reason, it keeps going off the screen in my computer, i don't know if its just me but here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)


label_frame = tk.Frame(root)
answer_label = tk.Label(label_frame, text="text")
answer_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label_frame.place(anchor = "n")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you give an `x` and `y` value when you place the `label_frame`?

Comment: I suggest using `.pack()` or `.grid()`

Comment: another suggestion: You can pack widgets right away and add stuff to them later

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this label go off screen when anchored?

Consider this line of code:

```
label_frame.place(anchor = "n")
```

The `anchor` option tells tkinter what part of the frame is to be placed at the given coordinates. `n` means "north", or the top-center of the frame. So, whatever coordinates are given, the top-center portion of the frame will be at those coordinates.

Since you did not give any coordinates, they default to x=0 and y=0. Thus, the top-middle portion of the frame will be placed at 0,0. That means that the left half of the frame will be to the left of coordinate 0,0.

If you insist on using `place`, and if you want the frame centered, you can give a `relx` of .5, meaning that the anchor position (`n`) will be placed half-way across the width of the containing widget.

```
label_frame.place(relx=.5, y=0, anchor = "n")
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
label_frame.place(anchor = "nw")
```

Tested this and it seems to put the label in the right place.